StorageApiError: new row violates row-level security policy
Using the Supabase Storage API, I am calling:
const createBucketRes = await supabase.storage.createBucket('avatars')

But I am getting the error

StorageApiError: new row violates row-level security policy

I am able to use the dashboard to create a bucket and set policies there, but then what is the purpose of having the API?
Reference: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/quickstart?queryGroups=language&language=javascript

You would have to define RLS policies to allow all users to create buckets.
Something like:
create policy "allow all users to create buckets"
ON storage.buckets
for insert with check (
  true
);

Or alternatively use the service role key as auth for the supabase client.
export default async function getSupabaseServerAdminClient() {
  const supabase = createClient<Database>(
    process.env.SUPABASE_URL!,
    process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY!,
    {
      auth: {
        persistSession: false,
        autoRefreshToken: false,
        detectSessionInUrl: false,
      },
    },
  );
  return supabase;
}

